# Android IME of multiple steps to compose a glyph

Tags: android, ime

Assume there is a character' 暂' that I want to write using a custom Android IME. If I want to show the said glyph when I press the key "G" followed by  "E", how do I go about it (G itself is assigned to another code).

I know I can assign many characters to the same label as follows and I will get different results based on the frequency of clicks using...

```
<Key android:codes="xx,yy" android:keyLabel="暂"/>
```

My goal is similar but some how different. I was hoping that I may be able to get the desired effect by doing something like ....

```
<Key android:codes="xx,xx+zz=yy" android:keyLabel="暂"/>
```

But that doesn't seem to be valid way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in XML, however, it can be done programmatically. You could overwrite the `onKey` listener (of a particular view or create a full new `InputType`) and use it to keep track of previous inputs. In case the listener finds that an "E" is preceded by a "G", for example, the output would be the key you specified. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330858/output-one-character-per-two-keys-in-android-keyboard) you find an implementation.